# Space-Filling Curve

Tags: analysis

How can I prove that there is no closed smooth space filling curve from [0,1] to 2-dimensional sphere.
I can construct a space filling curve to a cube in R^3, but why I can not expand it to sphere?

Comment: You may construct such a curve over every compact space.

Comment: @Blumer **But** it will basically never be smooth.

Comment: I didn’t understood the smoothness hypothesis. Sorry

Comment: As Daniel Robert-Nicoud hints in his reply to Blumer, "smooth" is the key word here. You can construct space-filling curves into the cube and the sphere, but neither one of those is smooth (i.e., possessing a continuous derivative). Proving that smooth curves cannot be space-filling requires some sophisticated analysis, though.